# bitbucket ci/cd "private-key.pem": invalid format error

Tags: bitbucket, cicd

i create bitbucket ci/cd pipeline.after i run pipeline error is occure.
that is,

"Load key "private-key.pem": invalid format"

```
image: php:8.1.16

pipelines:
  branches:
    QA:
      - step:
         name: QA
         caches:
          - composer
         script :
          - apt-get update && apt-get install unzip -y
          - apt-get install openssh-client -y
          - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > private-key.pem
          - chmod 600 private-key.pem
          - ssh -i private-key.pem ec2-user@15.202.30.100 'bash s' < execute.sh
```

this is my 'bitbucket-pipelines.yml' file. and i create private-key.pem variable.

anyone can help solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have made some changes to the script to improve its security. You can now use the ssh-keygen command to generate the public key **public-key.pem** and **ssh-keyscan** to add the host key of your EC2 instance to the *~/.ssh/known_hosts* file.
Don't forget to replace 15.202.30.100 with the actual IP address of your EC2 instance.

```
ssh-keygen -y -f private-key.pem > public-key.pem
ssh-keyscan 15.202.30.100 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```